# Bootstrap dropdown menu not dropping down?

Tags: bootstrap-4

The options for Bootstraps drop-down menu are not displaying. Tried moving min.js files, container divs etc, and nothing seems to be working. It seems others having this issue had bootstraps and ajax scripts in the wrong place. I believe mine are in the right place. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Concept Noise</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<style>

    .jumbotron{
        background: url(http://imgstore.wdwmagic.com/imgstore/ElementGalleryItems/attractions/Fullsize/Mission-SPACE_Full_1489.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
        color: white;
        height: 550px;
        text-shadow: black 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
        text-align: center;
        color: #ffffff;
    }


    .jumbotron h1{

        margin-top: 10%;
        font-size: 80px;
    }

    .jumbotron p{

        margin-top: 2%;
    }

    #button {

        margin-top: 10%;
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    }

    .btn, .btn:hover, .btn:active, .btn:visited {
        background-color: #2D92FF !important; 
    }


    .btn-xl {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        width:30%; 
 }   

</style>

<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded navbar-fixed-top" id="navbar">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Concept Noise</a>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#jumbotron">Destinations<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Easter Egg?</a>
        </li>
      </ul>  
 </nav>


  <div class="jumbotron">

    <h1>Concept Noise</h1>

    <p>Choose your destination, travel to another world.</p>

    <p><button type="button" id = "button" class="btn btn-xl btn-info">Epcot 1982</button></p>

  </div>

    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Destinations</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Please select your Destination
      <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href=""></a>Avatar land</li>
        <li><a href="#">The African Sehrengetty</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tommorowland 1970</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Futureworld 1982</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});

</script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Your code uses Bootstrap 4 alpha 2.  The current release is alpha 6. 
 There's been some work on the navbar in the various Bootstrap 4 alpha releases.  Try with alpha 6 and see if you still have problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **head** section paste this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Erase all script lines from **body** section including jquery "dropdown" code. **$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();**
}); Not sure why are you using 1.12.4 version of jquery since the current one is 3.2.1, here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Also, I would suggest not to use full width container but just div class="container" because your dropdown is all the way to the left, unless you will move it to the right a bit when clicked on it.

The second suggestion is to make it responsive as well. When resizing the window it should show hamburger menu for tablets and mobile devices.